# Como saber qual Botao foi clicado na minha ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Eu tenho uma ListView, em cada Linha Tenho dois botões.
Como posso saber qual botão foi clicado?

Segue meu codigo:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_imagen"
    android:layout_width="145dp"
    android:layout_height="145dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:contentDescription="Descripción del contenido de la imagen"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_superior"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_botao"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="CliqueBotao"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="right"

        android:layout_weight="0"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_inferior"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_botao2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="CliqueBotao2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="right"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Meu Adaptador:

```
public abstract class Lista_adaptador extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<?> entradas;
    private int R_layout_IdView;
    private Context contexto;

    public Lista_adaptador(Context contexto, int R_layout_IdView, ArrayList<?> entradas) {
        super();
        this.contexto = contexto;
        this.entradas = entradas;
        this.R_layout_IdView = R_layout_IdView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int posicion, View view, ViewGroup pariente) {
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) contexto.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R_layout_IdView, null);
        }
        onEntrada(entradas.get(posicion), view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return entradas.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int posicion) {
        return entradas.get(posicion);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int posicion) {
        return posicion;
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve cada una de las entradas con cada una de las vistas a la que debe de ser asociada
     *
     * @param entrada La entrada que será la asociada a la view. La entrada es del tipo del paquete/handler
     * @param view    View particular que contendrá los datos del paquete/handler
     */
    public abstract void onEntrada(Object entrada, View view);

}
```

E na minha ActicityMain, tenho os dois métodos dos botões:

```
CliqueBotao
CliqueBotao2
```

Mas sempre têm o mesmo id, porque estou definindo o id no `entrada.xml`, então são sempre os mesmos.

Como posso diferencia-los?

Comment: Queres saber qual dos dois foi clicado o 1 ou o 2? ou em que linha foi clicado?

Comment: Coloque o código do método `onEntrada()`

Comment: Cada linha é de um usuário, e contem dois botões...um de mensagem é outro que chama uma activity.... Na minha activityMain eu sempre pego eles do meu XML...para fazer as linhas...mas nesse momento eu queria setar um id diferente, para quando for clicado eu saber: esse botao é de mensagem de tal usuário... Na minha actMaim eu já tenho implementado os dois métodos que estão funcionando.... Mas qdo eu pego o id por view.id()...  Sempre vem o mesmo id de um e o mesmo id do outro....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) crie um method com View Argument.

2) use switch (ou if) usando view.getId() , esse method te retorna a int id do button que recebeu o evento (o click).

3) adicione o atribute `android:onClick="nomeDoMethod"`

código exemplo: (sendo listView o objeto da sua ListView)

```
 public void buttonClicked(View v)
 {
     int pos = listView.getPositionForView(view);

     switch(v.getId())
     {
         case R.id.bt_botao :
             Log.d("TAG","BUTTON 1 @ position: "+pos);
             break;
         case R.id.bt_botao2 :
             Log.d("TAG","BUTTON 2 @ position: "+pos);
             break:
         default :
         // caso aconteca algum erro 
         break;
     }
 }
```

agora dentro do `layout.xml` onde encontra os Buttons:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_botao2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="buttonClicked"
    />
```

PS: não será necessário o uso do `OnItemClickListener`.

Comment: Adriano...já estou fazendo isso...e os dois métodos estão funcionando qdo coloco nos botões ele entra no método...o meu problema está sendo em distinguir os botões...pq eu dou um findbyview(idBotao) para pega-los do XML...mas aí não consigo mudar o id pra distinguir dentro dos métodos...

Comment: e por isso vc tem q usar o `int pos = listView.getPositionForView(view);`  esse method vai te retornar o position do seu ListView onde o Button recebeu o evento (click) , ai vc usa como index do seu Array que vc passou pro seu Adapter, pelo q entendi o layout.xml onde encontra seus Buttons e o layout do item do seu ListView , entao voce so pode encontrar eles pela id + position

Comment: vi seu comentario , vc entao tem um array com ID's , faz um Log.d() dentro do case : e usa  'seuArrayId[pos]' o pos seria o index , ai vc pode pegar a id que vc quer

Comment: Ok, Adliano...deu certo do jeito que vc explicou de inicio...Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode inserir no `onCreate`:

```
 Button bt_botao2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_botao2 );
 bt_botao2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         //codigo a ser executado aqui
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá! Você vai saber qual botão clicou pelo id que você colocou no xml.
A unica coisa que você tem que se preocupar é de colocar o evento dentro do **getView** do seu adapter.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int posicion, View view, ViewGroup pariente) {

        // Birl

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) contexto.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R_layout_IdView, null);
        }
        onEntrada(entradas.get(posicion), view);

        Button bt_botao = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bt_botao);
        Button bt_botao2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bt_botao2);

        bt_botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Acao do primeiro botao
            }
        });

        bt_botao2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Acao do segundo botao
            }
        });


        return view;
    }
```